# python keeps rows from month (int) column when its equal to todaysdate function

Tags: python, date, python-datetime

Im trying to keeps the rows from a Df when the month columns (int) its equal to the todaysdate function.

i Just bring the month (int) from the todaysdate function. Heres is the code:

```
import time
todaysdateMes = time.strftime('%m')
todaysdateMes
```

And im tryin somethin like this to keeps the equalities

```
filtered_df = Reg_10.loc[(Reg_10['First Registration Status Date'] == [time.strftime('%m')])
filtered_df
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code worked for me if somebody need its:

```
filtered_df = Reg_10.loc[(Reg_10['First Registration Status Date'] == todaysdateMes)]
filtered_df
```